# Is it good practice to send ID from database table like GET parameter in URL?

Tags: php, get

I just want to ask one thing. I selecting books from database and displaying them as a list. When user pressing on book title, it takes him to book inner page. What i think that it simple make href with get parameter (ID) (This ID parameter is selecting from database). For example: `<a href="book/?id=12">Book title</a>`. Is it good practice to do this? Or better send other parameter, not id

Comment: It is perfectly normal. You might want to stick to RESTful representation though and have it `GET book/12` if you are getting book number 12.

Comment: Yes normally the ID is used for this ..

Comment: Hi, sending parameter is probably a good idea, sending anchor makes a lot more sense when you are doing somthing like paging, or where you would want the user to access the page they require by changing the url. It's upto your requirements.

Comment: depends; most likely open to an sql injection, given no code to support the mysql

Comment: your question IMHO falls into any of these categories: 1) too broad 2) unclear 3) opinion-based

Comment: why was this tagged as mysql?

Comment: I removed the mysql tag in an edit. You're obviously not paying attention to comments or you're just ignoring them. Up until that you can post relevance to "mysql", the tag should not be used as it is misleading.

Comment: I edited my question. I agree that mysql tag was misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as query string contains no sensitive information, it's totally fine. Passing ID like that is absolutely normal, even standard.

As a side note, if you're interested in SEO, you might want to pass book name in the URL, since URL content affects your ranking to a certain extend. So, having URL like `book/{book-id}-{bookname}` might be a good idea, e.g. `book/12344-critique-of-pure-reason`.

**UPDATE**

As @Fred -ii- reasonably notes, you must ensure that you're protected against SQL injection. Since you're willing to use simple integer IDs, it's quite simple to implement (on a very basic level):

```
<?php

if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {

    // Filter value of $_GET['id'] to prevent SQL injection
    //
    // This particular line removes all characters 
    // except digits, plus and minus sign from the passed parameter.
    $requestedId = filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

    // continue with querying your database

}
```

So, make sure you're doing this, otherwise your database is insecure.

Comment: you could add to your answer about possible sql injection. Then again, we don't know what their code looks like neither. (since it was tagged as mysql).

Comment: I selecting books from database and displaying them as list. For example <td><a href="/book/?id=12">Book name</a></td>. And when press on title, it should go to book inner page. So i asked this question, because i'm not sure if it is good to pass id from database as get parameter

Comment: @GeorgyIvanov [See my comment here...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177329/is-it-good-practice-to-send-id-like-get-parameter-in-url#comment71518472_42177329) to the OP.  But thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes no problem you can also send POST request instead of GET, i think will be better.

Comment: get/post what really is better? if their mysql isn't protected a possible sql injection, what good would POST do?

Comment: I know it's only about url, but i guess he didn't mean security here.

Comment: they tagged the question as mysql. So if that has nothing to do with the question, then they should remove the tag, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

solution 1

```
book/?ids=12,13,14
```

soluton 2:submit form as follows

```
<input name="id" value="12"/>
<input name="id" value="13"/>
<input name="id" value="14"/>
```

Comment: solution to what? you didn't grasp the question here